# Getting certain value from xml

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file and I have two values that I would like to take. Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <order created='2012-07-12T15:29:33.000' ID='2343'>
        <product>
            <description>Sony 54.6" (Diag) Xbr Hx929 Internet Tv</description>
            <gtin>00027242816657</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">2999.99</price>
            <supplier>Sony</supplier>
        </product>
        <product>
            <description>Apple iPad 2 with Wi-Fi 16GB - iOS 5 - Black</description>
            <gtin>00885909464517</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">399.0</price>
            <supplier>Apple</supplier>
        </product>
        <product>
            <description>Sony NWZ-E464 8GB E Series Walkman Video MP3 Player Blue</description>
            <gtin>00027242831438</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">91.99</price>
            <supplier>Sony</supplier>
        </product>
    </order>
    <order created='2012-07-13T16:02:22.000' ID='2344'>
        <product>
            <description>Apple MacBook Air A 11.6" Mac OS X v10.7 Lion MacBook</description>
            <gtin>00885909464043</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">1149.0</price>
            <supplier>Apple</supplier>
        </product>
        <product>
            <description>Panasonic TC-L47E50 47" Smart TV Viera E50 Series LED HDTV</description>
            <gtin>00885170076471</gtin>
            <price currency="USD">999.99</price>
            <supplier>Panasonic</supplier>
        </product>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I would like to get lets say the `<product></product>` where the `<supplier></supplier>` is apple.

This is the code that I have tried but it does not work:

```java
public void readXml() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\40723\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SACOM\\src\\sacom\\suppliers23.xml"));
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("orders");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if(node.hasAttributes()) {
            Attr attr = (Attr) node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("supplier");
            if(attr != null) {
                String attribute = attr.getValue();
                System.out.println("attribute: " + attribute);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Can someone give me a working example please I am a newbie in Java and XML.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: nodeList contains all the "orders" elements, of which there is only one. You need to iterate over its child elements. Also `supplier` is not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [The XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), to gain an understanding of its terminology.

In XML, an *element* is data that starts with a *tag,* like `<orders>`.  Any time a `<` is followed by a letter¹, it represents an XML element.

In XML, a *attribute* is a *name*`=`*value* pair **inside the start tag of an element.**

`<price currency="USD">` is the start of an element whose name is “price” which has one attribute.  That attribute’s name is “currency”.

`<product>` is the start of an element whose name is “product”.  It has zero name=value pairs, so there are zero attributes.

`<supplier>` is the start of an element which is a child of a `<product>` element.

What all of this means is that you should not be looking at attributes.  At all.

The easiest way to locate specific elements is with [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html):

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\40723\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SACOM\\src\\sacom\\suppliers23.xml"));
NodeList productElements = (NodeList)
    XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate(
        "//product[supplier='Apple']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If you want to stick to using the DOM (document object model), you can do that, but you need to look for elements:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\40723\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SACOM\\src\\sacom\\suppliers23.xml"));

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");
int productCount = nodeList.getLength();

List<Element> matchingProductElements = new ArrayList<>(productCount);

for (int i = 0; i < productCount; i++) {
    Element product = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

    NodeList supplierElements = product.getElementsByTagName("supplier");
    if (supplierElements.getLength() > 0) {
        String supplierValue = supplierElements.item(0).getTextContent();
        if ("Apple".equals(supplierValue)) {
            matchingProductElements.add(product);
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1. outside of a comment, prolog, processing instruction, or CDATA section</sup>